# £ sign not displaying in TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I have read through the answers regarding encoding for special characters and made the recommended changes but I am still having some problems with TCPDF. If I try and output a string which contains the £ sign, it only outputs the very first character of the string. For example, “Testing ££” is only outputting “T”.

I have included the below lines of my code:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 10, '', true);
$pdf->MultiCell(58, $rowcount * 4.5, $row["Job_Description"], 1, 'C', 0, 0,'','',True,0,False,True);
```

The string itself is coming out of a MySQL database, I used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the string before inserting it into the database and I am starting to wonder if that is causing a problem?

Comment: Did u try to replace `£` with `&pound;` ? Otherwise change `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried UTF-8 but just get the same. The initial string is a user input which I use mysqli_real_escape_string() on before inserting into a mysql database.

Comment: I think the next step would be to have a look at the output of  bin2hex($row["Job_Description"]) and see if you're getting the correct string of characters that would represent the pound sign (which I believe would be A3 in ISO-8859-1 and C2A3 in UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks for that JamesG, much appreciated. Will try that and come back to you. Cheers Tom

Comment: Hi, just tried it, it comes back blank, no output. The cell it sits in is created ok but nothing inside. Cheers Tom

Comment: @thomasogrady from the DOMPDF Faq: `Q: How can I print the euro symbol?
A: You can print the euro symbol (€) using the following entity: &#0128;.`